# Can not use Groovy collections with closures in Jenkinsfile script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to use groovy closures with collections in Jenkinsfile:

```
// other parts removed for brevity
steps {
    script {
        def testList = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
        testList.stream().map{it+".jpeg"}.each{println it}
    }
}
// other parts removed for brevity
```

However, it gives error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.map() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@248ba046]
Possible solutions: map(java.util.function.Function), max(java.util.Comparator), min(java.util.Comparator), wait(), dump(), grep()
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:49)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    ...
```

Comment: According to the error message, a closure is a not an acceptable type for the argument to the `map` method. Checking the documentation, it does appear the input type needs to be a lambda. I also note examples where the closure is expressed as a lambda to become an acceptable input type. Is there more code here to explain the context of the closure?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Given code snippet is working on normal groovy environment. jdoodle.com/ia/aHQ

Comment: versions of jenkins and java ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider that Jenkins pipelines are using a [Groovy CPS plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin), which implements a [continuation-passing style transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) on the program as it is compiled. That can lead to [pipeline CPS method mismatches](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/).

```
[ Jenkins Pipeline ]
       |
       | (executes)
       v
[ Jenkinsfile Script ]
       |
       | (transformed by)
       v
[ Groovy CPS Transformer ]
       |
       | (alters class types)
       v
[ CPS and Non-CPS Code Mixture ]
```

Given the transformation that occurs due to the Groovy CPS (Continuation-Passing Style) in a Jenkinsfile, it is important to adapt the coding style to avoid the method mismatch issue.
That transformation is what enables Jenkins to pause and resume the execution of a stage but can cause class type alterations leading to the error you see.

You have three possible approaches, depending on the nature of your task:

### 1. Adopt a Java (pre-lambda) style:

Reverting to a more traditional Java coding style, with for loops, can help avoid these CPS transformation issues.

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Process data') {
      steps {
        script {
          final Map myData = [
            "foo": "bar",
            "plop": "yo",
          ]
          for (def entry : myData) {
            println "${entry.key} → ${entry.value}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### 2. Global method usage with a method pointer operator

Similarly to your previous approach, defining methods globally and then referencing them using the method pointer operator can be a viable workaround.

```
void doSomething(final String key, final String value) {
  println "${key} → ${value}"
}

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Process data') {
      steps {
        script {
          final Map myData = [
            "foo": "bar",
            "plop": "yo",
          ]
          myData.each(this.&doSomething)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### 3. Use `@NonCPS` annotation:

In some scenarios, marking methods with the [`@NonCPS` annotation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#use-of-pipeline-steps-fromnoncps) can help, although it may not be suitable for all use cases due to its limitations (I.e.: "such methods must not call CPS-transformed code such as Pipeline steps").

```
@NonCPS
void printMap(Map myData) {
  myData.each { key, value ->
    println "${key} → ${value}"
  }
}

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Process data') {
      steps {
        script {
          final Map myData = [
            "foo": "bar",
            "plop": "yo",
          ]
          printMap(myData)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fighting the same problem--constructs in Groovy which I use all the time, like all the handy collection methods, are breaking.

It turns out that in a Jenkinsfile, the code is passed through a transformer called Groovy CPS which enables Jenkins to stop and restart execution of a stage. In the process, stuff gets changed from its original class, and this causes the kind of error you're seeing here, because you're mixing non-CPS code (the Java lib methods) with CPS code (anything inside the Jenkinsfile).

[Here's the link to the documentation of this behavior](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/)...but I didn't find it very helpful, so I am reverting to doing stuff like I would in Java (pre-lambda) with lots of for loops :(

Answer (score 0):

While it’s not as handy as locally defined closures, you can, in some cases, define methods in the global scope and then rely on them via [the Groovy method pointer operator](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-pointer-operator).

```
void doSomething(final String key, final String value) {
  println "${key} → ${value}"
}

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Process data') {
      steps {
        script {
          final Map myData = [
            "foo": "bar",
            "plop": "yo",
          ]
          myData.each(this.&doSomething)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following groovy code throws the same error as a jenkins-groovy code in question:

```
class MyClosure extends Closure{}

MyClosure c = {it+".jpeg"}
def testList = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
testList.stream().map(c).each{println it}
```

The issue that jenkins interprets closure as a custom closure class that is not autoconverted to java function

in jenkins try to avoid java streaming and anything around java Functions.

you can easily transform any streaming code to groovy native code:

```
steps {
    script {
        def testList = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
        println testList.collect{it+".jpeg"}.join('\n')
    }
}
```